# How to embed a SPA into an ASP.NET Core library and serve it from a path

Tags: angular, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, asp-net-core-spa-services

## Szenario

I want to build an aspnetcore library/module that **includes** a small **SPA** frontend. I.e. the html/js/css files should come along with the dll.
The SPA should be served from a specific path, i.e. `/some-module` (does *not* need to be configurable).
The SPA consists of several html/js/css files, lets assume following files:

```
/my-module/index.html
/my-module/index.js
/my-module/index.css
```

These urls should just server the files.
all other paths such as

```
/my-module/
/my-module/page-1
/my-module/page-2
```

should serve the index.html, so that client-side routing can handle the requests.

I have a partial solution, where the SPA files are served. However I don't know how to make all other subpaths i.e. `/my-module/*` (excluding the files) to return `index.html`.

## **Partial Solution using embedded files and UseFileServer:**

Assuming the SPA build files are located in `/my-library/web/build/`. The following csproj embeds these files into the dll using `GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest` and `EmbeddedResource`:

`my-module.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
    <SpaRoot>web\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="web\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="web\build\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The following middleware configuration serves these embedded files using the `ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider`:

```cs
        public static void UseMyModuleUi(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
            {
                RequestPath = "/my-module",
                FileProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(
                    assembly: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ServiceExtensions)), "web/build")
            });
        }
```

Calling the `UseMyModuleUi` extension method in some aspnetcore application that references my module, this does indeed serve the files under
`/my-module/index.html`
`/my-module/index.js`
`/my-module/index.css`

even `/my-module/` serves `my-module/index.html`.

However all other paths under `/my-module/` such as `my-module/page-1` do not serve `index.html`.#

## Alternatives I tried

I tried to use some combinations of `UseSpaStaticFiles` or `UseStaticFiles` and `Map`, however with no good results.

The project I am build is available here: https://github.com/jannikbuschke/ef-configuration-provider
the `ui` project is the library that embedds a SPA. The `sample` project is the host application.

Comment: Could you eventually find a solution?

Comment: No, I only found the partial solution above, which is not flexibel enough for my use case. Therefore I am not shifting to an approach where the frontend has a dedicated npm package, that can be consumed in the app. This approach allows for much greater flexibility from the app perspective, but is a bit work to set up properly.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you:

```cs
    public static void UseMyModuleUi(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/my-module", builder => 
        {
            var provider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(
                assembly: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ServiceExtensions)), "web/build"); 
            builder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
            {
                FileProvider = provider
            });
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.SendFileAsync(provider.GetFileInfo("index.html"));
            });
        });
    }
```

1. `Map` defines a new branch that gets executed when the request starts with the given path and removes that path segment from the for this branch.
2. The static file provider will match every file that exists in the `ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider`
3. In order to serve the `index.html` for every non-matching request, `Run` defines a delegate that always returns the given file. Thats your so called *catch-all* for this branch.