# How do I reference an embedded resource in a <script/> tag?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a ASPNET CORE website that references a separate class library.

In that class library I have a javascript file as an embedded resource.

IOW, I have this in MyLibrary.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    [...]

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="JavaScript/MyFile.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In the website project my _Layout.cshtml contains this:

```
<body>

    [...]

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

I would like to add a  tag, either to the end of the  element in _Layout.cshtml, or to the "Scripts" section within any of the .cshtml files that use _Layout.cshtml.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not simply put a file on your scripts folder?

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-5.0#manifest-embedded-file-provider also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965843/how-to-embed-a-spa-into-an-asp-net-core-library-and-serve-it-from-a-path

Comment: @Alejandro - because the file is a part of the library project, not the website project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have something mostly working.

First, some context. I have two projects, building two different assemblies. It can be difficult, when reading various "explanations" of how to make this work, to understand which assembly they were referring to, so I'm going to be pedantically explicit.

There are a number of steps:

1. Add the file to the library project.
2. Make it accessible as an embedded resource.
3. Map an endpoint in the web site that serves up the embedded resource file.
4. Add a <script> tag to the html that links to that endpoint.

**MyLibrary** is a class library project containing a number of classes, and a JavaScript file that I want to make available to any website that references those classes.

In it I have a directory "JavaScript", and in that the file "MyJsFile.cs" that I want to make available to the client.

I've installed the Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded NuGet package in MyLibrary, and I've set GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest to true.

And I've added the file I want to be available in an EmbeddedResource ItemGroup.

So MyLibrary.csproj looks like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    [...]
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="5.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="JavaScript/MyJsFile.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

At this point, I compiled MyLibrary, and checked to confirm that MyJsFile.js was listed as an embedded resource in MyLibrary.dll. On Windows, you can examine an assembly using ildasm.exe. If you're running on Linux, and don't want to bother with finding, downloading, and maybe having to build one of the various competing versions of ildasm that seem to be out there, you can just stick this into a project that's referencing MyLibrary, and step past it in the debugger:

```cs
var resourceNames = typeof(MyLibrary).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

You should see the name of the file, in resourceNames. You can extract the whole file with:

```cs
using (var resourceStream = typeof(MyLibrary).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyLibrary.JavaScript.MyJsFile.js"))
{
  var rdr = new StreamReader(resourceStream);
  var contents = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

**MyWebsite** is a ASP.NET Core Web App project that references MyLibrary, and it's this that I need to be able serve up the file.

First we need to reference the library project. MyWebsite.csproj:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    [...]
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../MyLibrary/MyLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Next, we need to map an endpoint in Startup.cs:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    [...]
    app.Map("/mylibrary", builder =>
    {
        var provider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(
            assembly: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyLibrary)), "JavaScript");
        builder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = provider
        });
    });
}
```

What this is doing is setting up a routing rule such that any reference to a file beginning with `/mylibrary` is mapped to an embedded resource of the same name in the `JavaScript` directory of `MyLibrary.dll`

Which means we can reference it in a <script> tag:

```xml
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/mylibrary/MyJsFile.js"></script>
    [...]
}
```

And this is working. The objects defined in MyJsFile.js are visible in the browser.

All that's left is to move the `App.Map("/mylibrary", [...])` configuration into an extension method in the library, so that `MyWebsite` doesn't need to know the details of how to configure it.

To do that, I need to add a couple of NuGet packages to `MyLibrary`:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

And then I needed to create an extension method in `MyLibrary`:

```cs
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder MapMyLibrary(this IApplicationBuilder app, string localPath)
    {
        app.Map(localPath, builder =>
        {
            var provider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(
                assembly: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "JavaScript");
            builder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = provider
            });
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

And then, finally, change Startup.cs, in `MyWebsite`, to call it:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    [...]
    app.MapMyLibrary("/mylibrary");
}
```